# .org pendingDelete release at what time of day

Tags: domains

Is there a particular time of day **.org** domains release? I've read on multiple forums/articles claiming different times, and even worse, all of the conversions of **GMT to ET/PT** were all incorrect as well.

So now, I'm a bit baffled at what the correct time is in GMT/PDT for time of day the .org is officially deleted from the registry.

Can anyone comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domains expire in CST time and `.org` domains the time is 9:30am CST, currently CST is -5 hours to that of GMT but due to daylight saving times this number changes throughout the year. So in other words if CST is -5 hours then you +5 that to GMT.

So as of now (25/06/2014) it is: - 9:30am CST / 2:30pm GMT / CEST 4:30pm

You should know that domains can take hours after that time to actually drop and thats why many people 'BID' on domains that expire, if its a short and highly desirable domain then the likeihood is that multiple servers will be hammering the whois and attempting to register the domain in a split second and making it impossible for a human to beat those services.